# send an object through ObjectOutputStream only one client

Tags: java

Suppose we have one server and two or more clients connected to it. The server wants to send through `ObjectOutputStream` an object so use it and open the server stream output using the method `getOutputStream()`. The server wants to send this file only to one determinate client that have one field setted in a certain way.
the server maintains in a list the object client with all its field. The server wants to send an object only to a client who has a field setted in a certain way.So the server iterates the list and after find that client send to it the object.but how can determinate into the net which is the client?

Comment: This is not a problem you can solve with sockets and object streams. I recommend reading up JMS.

Answer (score 1):

Have each client send its status to the server when it changes, or send the object to all the clients and let them ignore the message if their status is false.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this, you will need multiple connections and/or multiple round-trips. Either the clients have to actively sent their status to the server, or the server has to ask them. Or, thirdly, the server could send them all the same message, but with a flag included that means 'only pay attention if you are 'free'.'

Really, you'd be better off learning to use a message queue system. You could use, for example, Apache ActiveMQ, and you could use Spring/JMS or Apache CXF Soap over JMS.